# Algorithm that checks if a subspace of states contains a product state

Tags: quantum-information, computational-physics, algorithms, tensor-network

Suppose I have two identical qudits, the full Hilbert space is $\mathcal{H}=(\mathbb{C}^{d})^{\otimes 2}$. Say I'm given a supspace of states $\Lambda\subset \mathcal{H}$. What is the fastest algorithm to check (and potentially find) if $\Lambda$ contains a direct product state of the form $|a\rangle\otimes |a\rangle$ (or maybe more generally $|a\rangle\otimes |b\rangle$)?